# Excel VBA Listbox displays more times than expected

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

My macro goes through all data rows on a specific sheet.  Currently there are 6 rows.  The first row is a negative number and the 2nd row is a positive number (debit and credit).

The macro reviews each row and displays a list box for the user to make a selection.  Then it goes through the next row and does the same thing.  I'm expecting the listbox to display 6 times, once for each row of data.

The problem I'm having is that the listbox is displaying 7 times.  3 times for the first pair or records and twice for the remaining pair of records.  I can't figure out why the listbox is displaying the extra time.

Here is the code for the list box:

```
Private Sub ContinueButton_Click()
    If IsNull(ListBox1.Value) Then
        MsgBox " Please select the appropriate balance to continue. "
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MyIndex = 0
        MyIndex = ListBox1.ListIndex
        MyIndex = MyIndex + 1
        
        MyBal = ""
        MyBal = APIARArray(MyIndex, 4)
    
       Unload UserForm1
       UserForm1.Hide
    
       Sleep 750
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Please select the appropriate balance for Unit: " & vUnit

    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 4
    ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "50;50;75;50"
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    With ListBox1
        w = 1
        i = 0
        
        For w = 1 To UBound(APIARArray)
            DoEvents
                .AddItem
                .List(i, 0) = APIARArray(w, 1)
                .List(i, 1) = APIARArray(w, 2)
                .List(i, 2) = APIARArray(w, 3)
                .List(i, 3) = format(APIARArray(w, 4), "#,##0.00;[Red](#,##0.00)")
                        
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End With
    
    UserForm1.Height = 215
    UserForm1.Width = 348
    
    ListBox1.SetFocus
    
End Sub
```

This is the code that calls the ListBox:

```
Sub LookForBalance()

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim APIUnit As String
    r = 2
    
    Do Until Len(Trim(Cells(r, 1))) + Len(Trim(Cells(r, 7))) + Len(Trim(Cells(r, 9))) + Len(Trim(Cells(r, 10))) + Len(Trim(Cells(r, 11))) = 0
        
        DoEvents
                    
        If Trim(Cells(r, 27)) = "A199" Then
            If Cells(r, 29) > 90 Then
                APIUnit = ""
                vUnit = ""
                vUnit = Trim(Cells(r, 11))
                    
                If MyCntry = "A1" Then APIUnit = clsAPI.APIARSearch("WWW11", Trim(Cells(r, 11)))         
                If MyCntry = "A2" Then APIUnit = clsAPI.APIARSearch("WWW12", Trim(Cells(r, 11)))         
                    
                If InStr(1, APIUnit, "ERROR") > 0 Then
                    Cells(r, 30) = "Unit Not Found"
                Else
                    If UBound(APIARArray) > 1 Then
                        Load UserForm1
                        UserForm1.Show
                    
                        Cells(r, 30) = MyBal                                                                            
                    Else
                        Cells(r, 30) = APIARArray(1, 4)                                                                                 
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

There isn't much code here but I'm not sure what is going on.  Any help or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your help.....

Comment: What does "display more times" should mean? Is the list box loaded with more than 6 rows, you are talking about? Which of your three codes creates the problem you try explaining? In order to resolve "the issue" you should try a little better describing it...

Comment: @FaneDuru..........Sorry I wasn't more clear.  There is a group number and unit number on each line.  The macro takes those 2 pieces of information and runs a query (API search that populates the list box. 

There are 3 pairs of data where the unit and group number is the same (6 lines).  The form with the list box should only display 6 times but it is displaying 7 times.  

On the first 2 lines, it displays 3 times and should only display twice.  The form only displays 4 times on the next 4 lines; just like I expect it to.....

Comment: @FaneDuru......For some reason the form is being displayed an extra time on the first 2 lines.....

Comment: Put `MsgBox r` before `UserForm1.Show` so you can see the row number that is causing each display event. Check columns 1,7,9,10,11 for those rows.

Comment: If it is a matter of the way the list box is loaded and the list box is populated based on `APIARArray`, you should show us how this array is built. If my understanding is correct, I do not see how you you can be helped, in these circumstances.

Comment: @CDP1802...............Thanks......I'll give that a try

Comment: @FaneDuru.........In my original post it, shows how the array is built.  What I'm seeing is when the macro hits the "Unload UserForm1" code, it jumps to the initialize subroutine.  I wouldn't have expected that.

Comment: @Savers Put the `UserForm1.Hide` before `Unload UserForm1`. Do you  actually need to unload the form ?

Comment: @CDP1802........Thanks.......i believe the answer to your question is yes.  Each time the form is disp,ayed, the list box should display different information

Comment: @Savers..............putting the "hide" before the "unload" seemed to resolve the issue I was having.  Thanks for your help......

Comment: @CDP1802..........putting the "hide" before the "unload" seemed to resolve the issue I was having. Thanks for your help.....